# How was the second inequality derived?

Tags: limits, inequality

This is inequality number 1:

$$8 < x + 5 < 10$$

How was this second inequality:

$$8 < x + 5 =|x+5|<10$$

derived from the first one (inequality number 1)?

Comment: It is the same. It simply adds that, since $x+5>8 (>0)$, it is equal to its absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$8<x+5<10 \implies x+5>0$$

therefore $x+5=|x+5|$.

Comment: From what I understood from your answer, we are using the fact that x+5>8>0 (i.e that it is positive) to say that x+5=|x+5|. However, how do we go from **a)8<x+5<10 to **b)8<x+5=|x+5|<10. In other words,how is the "equality" in **a) arrived at from the inequality in **b)

Comment: Yes exactly, since $x+5$ is a positive number (inequality 1) then $x+5=|x+5|$. This last equality is always true for $x\ge -5$. In this case from inequality $1$ we have that $3<x<5$ and therefore the two expressions are equivalent, as for example $8<9<10$ and $8<9=|9|<10$. It would be useful to have more context to understand why the second inequality has been considered.

Comment: here is the question asked with the full context https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797237/proving-limit-using-the-definition-of-a-limit

Comment: I’ve seen that. The aim is to find $K$ such that $|x+5|<K$ and since we are assuming $|x-4|<1$ we have $3<x<5$ and therefore $8<x+5<10$ that is $|x+5|<10$.